# Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present

Tags: java, http

Hit into this error of content length header already present when i'm trying to do a http requests using closeable http request

```
    package com.dotcomculture.arbbot;

    import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;

    public class ArbBot {

public static void main(String [ ] args)throws Exception{
System.out.println("I am in main" );
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://api.sandbox.gemini.com");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Length", "0");
httpPost.setHeader("X-GEMINI-APIKEY", "API KEY HERE");
httpPost.setHeader("X-GEMINI-PAYLOAD", "Payload here");
httpPost.setHeader("X-GEMINI-SIGNATURE", "Signature here");
httpPost.setHeader("Cache-Control", "0");

CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

int statusCode = closeableHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
System.out.println("Status Code : " +statusCode );




}

    }
```

POM.XML below

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

How do i remove the default content length header? anyone knows?

Comment: Why do you set Content-Type (indicating that the request has a body *and* try to set Content-Length to 0?

Comment: Hi I was using the API format from https://docs.gemini.com/rest-api/#private-api-invocation

Comment: Well, surprise, a badly specified HTTP API.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to solve the problem by commenting out the line // httpPost.setHeader("Content-Length", "0");

Comment: FWIW: this is a very good example of an API that calls itself "ReST", but really has no Rest-related quality at all. Apparently it's all RPC-style with custom request header fields.